# Unsure if motor starter (contactor + overload) is needed instead of normal solid state relay

Tags: relay, three-phase, inrush-current, single-phase, contactor

I am designing a system with several pumps ranging from 0.5 to 1.5 HP (all single phase) and am unsure of what kind of circuitry I need. I researched different motor contactors and overloads I could use, but I also have found relays that provide up to 40A, which is more than enough for my highest load of 30A. I mostly read that contactors are better at handling three phase and for inrush currents. I would appreciate any help on this topic.

Comment: What is the AC Mains voltage?

Comment: 120VAC, 230VAC, and some with 12VDC